# How can I scrape the social network for a subset of users in Twitter?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, social-media

Clearly one cannot scrawl the entire network... but I'd like to extract a statistically representative sample from the network. More specifically,

***I'd like to access the graph induced by scraping the follower connections between Twitter users with specific Klout scores.***
And then do the same for other networks too.

**Motivation:** My interest is to study and track the propagation of hashtags across the network.

Comment: The post you link to, dated 4/15/15, states that: "At the end of this month, however, Facebook will be deprecating the API we relied on to extract much of this information." Wouldn't that mean that by now the API is deprecated and the access is gone?